# How to Dynamically change the friendly name in Twilio Flex Webchat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-flex

So, I am following along the tutorial [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/installing-and-using-flex-webchat#option-1) on how to setup Twilio Flex WebChat. While it certainly works, I need to change the friendly name later on.

The way my app works, it shows the webchat **before** users sign since the scripts are in the index.html file of the react app.

I need to change it so that **after** they login it will update the name displayed in the chat.

This is what I have so far, but it certainly doesn't work. Assume I can get the names from local storage, and login stuff works.

```
componentDidMount() {
 //other stuff
this.initializeTwilio();
}

initializeTwilio() {
  const name = localStorage.getItem("firstName") +' '+ localStorage.getItem("lastName");
  const appConfig = {
    accountSid :"hidden",
    flexFlowSid: "hidden",
    context: {
      friendlyName: name
    }
  };
  Twilio.FlexWebChat.renderWebChat(appConfig);
}
```

I have also tried doing this:

```
  let test = Twilio.FlexWebChat.Manager.create(appConfig);
  Twilio.FlexWebChat.ContextProvider.Manager = test;
  Twilio.FlexWebChat.renderWebChat(appConfig);
```

I have also tried editing the MessagingCanvas like so:

```
 initializeTwilio =() => {
    const first = localStorage.getItem("firstName");
    let name ="";
    if(first){
      const last = localStorage.getItem("lastName");
      name = first +' '+ last;
    }
    else { 
      name = "Anonymous";
    }
    Twilio.FlexWebChat.MessagingCanvas.defaultProps.memberDisplayOptions = {
      yourDefaultName: name,
      yourFriendlyNameOverride: true
    }
    console.log(Twilio.FlexWebChat.MessagingCanvas.defaultProps);
}
```

This will change the value in the console but not the displayed name in the chat window.

[image: Screenshot of it not working]

I think I need to update the appconfig and re-render the chat window, but not sure how to do it and there may be a different way to solve the problem. I am open to being enlightened on this one.

Comment: have you tried `config = { chatFriendlyName: 'you' }`? I think some of their docs is not up-to-date. [config](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-webchat-basic-configuration) shows `config.context.friendlyName` while the table shows `config.chatFriendlyName`

Comment: @seanplwong, certainly haven't tried it. Is the correct approach still to re-render the webchat?  Basically I know how to set it initially, but need change it dynamically after it the initial setup.

Comment: I'm not familiar with twilio in fact, i just took a quick look in the doc and found sth not consistent. Maybe you could try create a new ContextProvider as illustrated in [the example](https://github.com/twilio/flex-webchat-ui-sample/blob/master/src/App.js). Or you could play around with `manager.chatClient`, [the doc](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.0.2/docs/User.html) shows there is a `friendlyName` attribute, but note that even if the state is updated, the ui might not

Comment: Hi @AlexanderRyanBaggett were you able to solve this? If so how? I have similiar requirement where I have to change config after user logs in (basically remove the pre-engagement form). Not able to achieve this. calling `FlexWebChat.renderWebChat(appConfig)` again throws error `default store already exists`. Do you have any idea how to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: @KishoreBarik, sorry, still haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you want to show exactly agent's name or something else. But here is what i found by accident in order to display agent's friendlyName

```
MessagingCanvas: {
  memberDisplayOptions: {
    theirFriendlyNameOverride: true
  }
}
```

`theirFriendlyNameOverride` flag overrides default friendly name of an agent once it's available

example of my config:

```
var appConfig = {
  accountSid: "xxxxxx",
  flexFlowSid: "xxxxx",
  componentProps: {
    MessagingCanvas: {
      memberDisplayOptions: {
        yourDefaultName: 'You',
        yourFriendlyNameOverride: false,
        theirFriendlyNameOverride: true
      }
    },
  },
  startEngagementOnInit: true,
};
```

Comment: I have tried setting the value in MessagingCanvas. It updates an object, but not the actual displayed name.

Comment: this is default settings props. twilio will override themselves.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett this is in case you want to display agents friendly name, not custom whatever you want

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett added example of my config, this config does the thing i want. maybe you need something else

Answer (score 0):

I had this situation I managed to make a workaround
I'm fetching data from the URL inside the configurations file
webchat-appConfig.js and then set friendlyName value from the parameter value

first to get the url of the route :
`const queryString = window.location.search;`

and then use URLSearchParams to convert the URL as key and value :
`const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);`

asume that the link you start the WebChatUi with : localhost:3000/userName=Muhammed

put them together and should be like that :

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
var appConfig = {
    //  change the your AccountSid
    accountSid: "A**************************",
    // change to your Flex Flow SID
    flexFlowSid: "FO*******************",
    colorTheme: {
        overrides: brandedColors
    },
    context: {
        friendlyName: urlParams.get('userName')
    },
}
```